# Stack Overflow Careers account disappeared

Tags: support, jobs, user-accounts

My Stack Overflow [Careers account](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/rexadrivan) seems to have disappeared from my account.

My Stack Overflow account is merged with my Careers account but now it has disappeared and it looks like I have to start all over again.

Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[image: Welcome!]

What can I do to get access back to my earlier Careers profile?

Comment: works for me. What is the problem?

Comment: @rene here's the screenshot my stackoverflow account is merged with my career account. but now it disappeared on my account :O

Comment: @RexAdrivan Everything looks good on my end. You probably logged in with a different account that what is attached to your profile. Can you click on "new user" in the top corner and let me know what the URL is?

Comment: @juice it's ok now